# C pass address of a function return value as function parameter

Tags: c, function, memory-address

I have two functions:

```
void a(int * p);
int b();
```

Is it possible to pass the address of the return value of function `b` to function `a` something like this: `a(&b())` ?

Comment: Surely the return value is a temporary - how could taking its address be useful?

Comment: Despite a majority of answers here, it is possible using compound literals.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A compound literal seems to do the trick (requires a C99 compiler):

```
int a()
{
    return 5;
}

void b(int *a)
{
    // do something with a
    printf("%d\n", *a);
}

int main(void)
{
    b(&(int){ a() });
}
```

Output is `5`.

Comment: This one looks amazing, but the compiler I have to use in older than C99, so there is no support of compound literals. However, I like this "solution" the best.

Comment: @papaiatis: C99 is nearly 14 years old, maybe it's time to update :)

Comment: I wish I could. :) My hands are tied.

Answer (score 3):

Only by using a temporary variable:

```
int result = b();
a(&result);
```

EDIT: Apparently there's also a way to do this using a compound literal, described in another answer here.

Comment: There is a way to do it without a temporary variable, using a compound literal.

Answer (score 2):

Nope - what would be the address of that return value? You need to store the return value in a variable, then pass the address of that variable in.

Answer (score 2):

No. C11 says that (emphasis mine):

> 6.5.3.2.1
>
> The operand of the unary & operator shall be either **a function designator**, the result of **a []** or **unary *** operator, or **an lvalue** that designates an object that is not a bit-field and is not declared with the register storage-class specifier.

Now it clearly isn't a function, a `[]` or a unary `*`. Let's see what is an *lvalue*:

> 6.3.2.1
>
> An lvalue is an expression (with an object type other than void) that potentially
>   designates an object;64) if an lvalue does not designate an object when it is evaluated, the
>   behavior is undefined. ...
>
> <sub>64) The name ‘‘lvalue’’ comes originally from the assignment expression E1 = E2, in which the left
>   operand E1 is required to be a (modifiable) lvalue. It is perhaps better considered as representing an
>   object ‘‘locator value’’. What is sometimes called ‘‘rvalue’’ is in this International Standard described
>   as the ‘‘value of an expression’’.</sub>
>
> <sub>An obvious example of an lvalue is an identifier of an object. As a further example, if E is a unary
>   expression that is a pointer to an object, *E is an lvalue that designates the object to which E points.</sub>

So in short, an lvalue designates an object. Since `b()` doesn't designate a specific object, it is not an lvalue. You can tell this by seeing also that `b() = 2;` is wrong.

Comment: Despite this, it is still possible with compound literals, see my answer.

Comment: @dreamlax, the compound literal makes an anonymous object in your answer, so it's basically the same as writing `int res = b(); a(&res);`. My answer says why specifically the OP's code won't work. Your answer is quite nice though, it had never occurred to me that you could do that.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't do that in `C`. Also note `C` doesn't have something called as *reference* as in `C++`.

For that `C` has **pointers** to achieve the same behaviour..

To achieve the same goal in `C` use temporary variable like,

```
int val;
val = b();
a( &val );    // & is called as "address of" operator in C
```

---

To answer why there is no *reference* in `C`, from my understanding pointer and reference are meant to achieve the same goal - **minimizing or avoiding data copy**. For this `C`'s pointer is good enough, though technically both have some difference in `C++` *(taken for reference)*

Comment: Why? Are there other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a reference to `b()` as an argument to `a` then call `b` from `a`:

```
void a(void (*b)(int)) {
   // call b
   int local_var = b(<something>);
}
```

Comment: Wow, you looked at this from a completely different angle.  Do you like Lisp, by any chance?  :-)

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin I love Lisp actually (well Scheme), so *a* Lisp.